# Boolean Abstraction C Program

Tags: c, boolean, abstraction

I'm trying to compute the abstraction of the following C code fragment, with the predicate: `b: { x >= 0 }`

```
1. if( x > 5 )
2.   x = x - 2;
3. else
4.   x = abs( x ) + 6;
5. assert( x >= 0 );
```

so far I abstracted:

```
1. if( * ) // not sure if I should put if( b ) here
2.   assume( b ); b = true;
3. else
4.   assume( true ); // ? don't know how to abstract further
5. assert( b )
```

Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: In the second code, line 2. Shouldn't there be a block around the two statements?

Comment: @Papergay:- You forgot `true`.

Comment: I do not think the abstraction is C code; I think it is intended to be statements in a formal logic used to reason about programs. The question is not clear.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev: There should be normally, but this is abstracted code, it's not to be compiled, so I think it's irrelevant whether there are braces or not.

Comment: Clarification:  This sort of abstraction is used by the SLAM tools.  The result of the abstraction of the above C code fragment should be a boolean program, and this is in turn a C program in which all variables have boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether I am understanding you correct or not, but for the set of input predicate `{x>=0}` or `b` (used alternatively).It should be:-

```
{x>=0}=unknown()   //unknown function is used to generate true or false non-deterministically

if(*)
{
 assume({x>=0});
 {x>=0}=true;
}
else
{
 assume(!{x>=0});
 {x>=0}=false;
}
```

Comment: But if you compute `abs(x) + 6` under the condition that `x <= 5`, then `x >= 0`, therefore shouldn't `{x>=0} = true`?

Comment: No, no, the condition x<=5 comes from the x>5. If !(x>5) then it has to be x<=5, right?  If we then take concrete values, say x = 3, then the else branch would trigger, and x = abs(3) + 6 would satisfy x >= 0...

Comment: I think it should go something like this:
`if( * ) {`
`assume( b ); b = b? * : false;`
`}`
`else`
`b = true;`
`assert( b );`  What do you think ?